# Не хочет меняться фон рабочего стола

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Написал небольшой код, который на рандоме выбирает картинку из папки и меняет фон рабочего стола. Запустил код , работает без ошибок, каждые три секунды получаю в терминал 'Background changed' НО сам фон рабочего стола не хочет меняться

Вот мой код:

```
import os
import time
import random

# Путь к папке с изображениями
image_folder = "/home/oleksii/Изображения/4k"
# Получение списка файлов в папке
image_files = os.listdir(image_folder)

while True:
    print('Background changed')
    image_file = random.choice(image_files)
    image_path = os.path.join(image_folder, image_file)
    command = "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file://{}'".format(image_path)

    os.system(command)
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: А сама по себе команда `gsettings set ...` в терминале меняет фон?

Comment: кстати, не работает